# PnP Framework Interactive MultiFactorAuth

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, .net

I keep going round and round on this as it seems I keep getting out of date examples. I need to create a simple Sharepoint Admin Application and I keep failing at Authentication.

I need a way to create a ClientContext using Interactive MFA. I just want a popup that allows the user to type in a username and password. I'm trying to use CreateWithInteractiveLogin with AuthenticationManager, but can't find a simple example where I can just hand it our sharepoint url.

I have the following Packages installed. Am I going by this the wrong way?
Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM (16.1.23408.12000)
PnP.Framework (1.11.0)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Can you share a snippet of what you have? I'm using same packages, just slightly older versions.

Comment: The problem is, I can't find an example to actually do it. I downloaded PnP.Framework source code and looked at it directly and I can't find any actual MFA ways to create a ClientContext.   But if I download the CSOM for PowerShell, it clearly has a way to do it. This is so frustrating.

Comment: Looking through all the PnP.Framework source code, it seems to only work with Applications and lost a simple way of doing MFA for a UserName. I'm at a loss. I've posted this issue in another well known help site. If nobody knows the answer here, maybe they will there. If they do, I will post the solution here.